# Send two PUT requests simultaneously

Tags: rest, rest-assured

Im having to test a REST API to change the height of an Ad but in order to do it i have to change the width simultaneously to make it work . im using REST Assured .

```
 given().auth().basic(ACCSID,AUTHTOKEN).when().put(advUri+ADID+"ThirdPartyServableAdCreativeHeight=600").then().statusCode(200)
 given().auth().basic(ACCSID,AUTHTOKEN).when().put(advUri+ADID+"ThirdPartyServableAdCreativeWidth=600").then().statusCode(200);
```

i need to send them simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

As of the currently released version (2.5.0) you can't (unless you handle threading yourself). There's an [issue](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/issues/462) for this which you can track if you like.